# Angular form reset not changing validity of form and field

Tags: angularjs

After I changed the validity of form field; form and field validity status are false even I run `$setPristine` and `$setUntouched` on form.

What's the correct way of resetting form in Angular?

Here is the plunker;

https://plnkr.co/edit/wftRm1H6TK8rRafHVDJV?p=preview

Comment: Demo is using angular version 1.01 which is ancient and doesn't have all the form upgrades done over the years. Use a current version and note which version you are actually using in project

Comment: actually version in the actual project is "1.4.7" and same problem exists. I'll update fiddle to demonstrate. I'm not familiar with Jsfiddle that's why I couldn't set the version at first.

Comment: Put the demo in `plunker` easy to set up there as full html document along with other files

Comment: Why just not using `$scope.user = {name : "", age : ""};`?

Comment: @charlietfl I updated it to plunker, angular version is 1.5.5 and still is not working.

Comment: @AndreaM16 how is that related?

Comment: Add this in demo `<pre>{{testForm|json}}</pre>` can see whole object

Comment: I have added it @charlietfl

Comment: I think I found a workaround. Explicitly setting setValidity(true) on input is solving issue. I was assuming setPristine should do it also. Is this a bug?